# Compare two chars of different strings in C

Tags: c, string, char, compare, equals

Hi I want to compare two chars of different strings in C and it's not working, help me please:

```
int main (void)
{

    string b="blue";
    int len=strlen(b);
    int numbers[]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25};
    string letters="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    int leng=strlen(letters);
    int key [len];


    for (int i=0; i<len;i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<leng;j++)
        {

            if (&b[i]==&letters[j])
            {
                //The program never comes inside here 
                key[i]=numbers[j];
            }
        }

    }

    //The result should be key[]={1,11,20,4 }
}
```

Comment: Is this really C++? Obviously `std::string` doesn't exist in C...

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
b[i]==letters[j]
```

instead of

```
&b[i]== &letters[j]
```

The latter compares pointer values.

Comment: ... and since these are two different objects, their pointers ought never to be the same (they are in different locations in memory).

Comment: Also note that the elements of `key` will not necessarily be assigned sequentially; there may be unassigned elements. You probably want an additional variable to count what you're writing to `key`.

Comment: ... and `strlen()` should not be mixed with `std::string` (just use the `length()` member function instead). Nothing wrong with your answer, just suggesting other points that could be incorporated to make it more complete.

Comment: @dvnrrs the question is tagged as C, so I assume `string` is something  like `typedef char string[];` and not `std::string`.

Comment: I asked the OP for clarification on that, I suspected he really meant C++ instead of C, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Whil @ouah gave you the short answer (why your code is not working), you might be interested in noting that the ascii value of a character is its "value", so you can achieve what you wanted more efficiently with

```
string b="blue";
int len=strlen(b);
int key [len]; // not sure what version of C allows this... compiler needs to know size of array at compile time!


for (int i=0; i<len;i++)
{
    key[i]=b[i] - 'a';
}
```

For a "standard C" solution, you need a couple more changes:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  char b[] = "blue";
  int len = strlen(b);
  int *key;
  key = malloc(sizeof(b) * sizeof(int));

  for (int i=0; i<len;i++)
  {
    key[i]=b[i] - 'a';
    printf("key[%d] = %d\n", i, key[i]);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int compare_two_strings(const char* text, const char* text2){
   int evaluate = 0;
   do {
       evaluate |= *text ^ *text2++;
   } while (*text++);
   return !(int)evaluate;
}

int main(void)
{
   const char* text =  "Hello";
   const char* text2 = "Hello";

   if (compare_two_strings(text, text2))
     printf("These strings are the same!");
   else printf("These strings are not the game!");

}
```

The `compare_two_strings(const char* text, const char* text2)` XOR's two values, checks if they are equal, and if they are it's OR'ed to the evaluate variable and then it advances to the next character.

It does this until it reaches the end of the string, then it'll leave the `do while` loop and return the evaluate value.